# How can I copy one element to another with angular legacy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets say I have 2 divs side by side. (for the sake of argument using bootstrap lets say they are both 6 columns each)

If I drag an object into the column on the right, and then click a button below that column, I want the column on the left to mirror the one on the right. (so they are now identical)

I know we can do this with 2 way binding in real time, but I am wondering if it is possible to invoke 2 way binding on a click event? I also looked into angular copy, but there is very little documentation on this that i understand.

```
   <div class="col-sm-12">

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-sm-12 left_column">
        <p>{{master}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-12 right_column">{{source}}</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="update()">Submit Changes</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-4 drag_item_1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 drag_item_2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 drag_item_3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

   .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', 
      function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider.state('homepage', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "templates/homepage.html"
  })
}])

.controller('swap_ctrl', function(){
$scope.source = "can it work?";
$scope.update = function() {
    angular.copy($scope.source, $scope.master);
};
  });
```

I know the code above doesnt work. It was just an attempt at trying to understand angular.copy. But it should give you an idea behind the structure. I was just going to use dragula to handle the dragging of objects to the right column.

Comment: could you provide a example of what are you trying to achieve and fail?

Comment: paste us some code..

Comment: Done. The code has been pasted.

Comment: @JoshWinters Were you able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your actual code looks like, but let's assume you have two arrays that represent your columns:

```
$scope.columnsLeft = [...];
$scope.columnsRight = [...];
```

And view markup looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columnsLeft track by $index"></div>
<div ng-repeat="column in columnsRight track by $index" ng-click="copyColumnToTheLeft(column, $index)"></div>
```

The [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) could be inside the `div` element and it could be applied to the button. Then the method `copyColumnToTheLeft` which will copy our column could look like this:

```
$scope.copyColumnToTheLeft = function (column, index) {
   $scope.columnsLeft[index] = angular.copy(column);
};
```

[Using angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) will create a copy of the `column` passed to the method, so changing the `column` (in right array) in future will not immediately show the changes on the left panel, since it would be a different object.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** In your particular case, you are going to have 2 arrays, one is `master` and second one is `source`:

```
$scope.master = [...];
$scope.source = [...];
```

If you are going to modify `source` array using dnd then your update method could look like:

```
$scope.update (){ $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.source); };
```

Anyway a [good example of how it works is on the official docs page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy#example).